# classify text using 'from text' and 'to text' in the dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Here is my toy data (Note that in my original data, I have 100s of rule sets i.e. such from to combinations):

```
rule_set <- tibble::tribble(
      ~if_you_see,  ~write,
    "honda civic",   "car",
  "toyota camery",   "car",
      "honda CRV",   "car",
            "boy", "human",
           "girl", "human")
```

Following is the dataframe with the text to be classified using the rule set in the above data frame. So, if you see the car names (given in the above data frame) in the below text, you write 'car' and if you see the entries boy or girl, you write 'human'.

```
to_be_classified <- tibble::tribble(
                                        ~text,
       "I have a honda civic. It pretty good.",
  "The toyota camery is also good. I like it",
                   "That boy has a honda CRV.",
           "You see that girl in blue dress?")
```

Here is the desired output:

```
desired_output <- tibble::tribble(
                                        ~text,       ~class,
       "I have a honda civic. It pretty good.",        "car",
  "The toyota camery is also good. I like it",        "car",
                  "That boy has a honda CRV.", c("human, car"),
           "You see that girl in blue dress?",      "human")
```

I started thinking on the following lines, but could not move forward.

```
library(tidyverse)
to_be_classified %>% 
      mutate(class = if_else(str_detect(text, pattern = rule_set$if_you_see), if_you_see$write))
```

Please advise, preferably with code involving dplyr and stringr functions.

Comment: Good catch! Sorry about the typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)


patterns_df <- rule_set %>% 
  group_by(write) %>% 
  summarise(
    patterns = paste(if_you_see, collapse = "|")
  )


to_be_classified %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    class = list(str_detect(text, patterns_df$patterns) %>% 
      patterns_df$write[.]),
    class = paste(unlist(class), collapse = ", ")
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   text                                      class     
#>   <chr>                                     <chr>     
#> 1 I have a honda civic. It pretty good.     car       
#> 2 The toyota camery is also good. I like it car       
#> 3 That boy has a honda CRV.                 car, human
#> 4 You see that girl in blue dress?          human
```

Comment: Your `car_patterns` return `"\\bhonda|civic|toyota|camery|CRV\\b"` whereas I think "honda" and "civic" must be together to be detected as "car"

Comment: This is a great solution for the toy example, but how can I scale this solution up for 100s of rule sets? Sorry for not clarifying that in the original question!

Comment: As an example for my comment, the sentence "I'm teaching civics" would be classified as "car"

Comment: @shafee 'honda civic' is one combined phrase so is 'toyota camery'.

Comment: Yes, it works now, though not scalable to 100s of from to to cases yet.

Comment: Yeah like filter(write == "car") and filter(write == "human") there are 100s of such entries.

Comment: @Geet, I have updated my code, Can you tell me whether it is scalable now??

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiarized with stringr functions, but I could suggest this line of code:

```
to_be_classified %>% 
  
  mutate(class = sapply(rule_set$if_you_see, grepl, x = text) %>% 
           apply(1, function(x) paste(rule_set$write[x], collapse = ", ")))
```

Using a `str_detect` function instead of `grepl`:

```
to_be_classified %>% 
  
  mutate(class = sapply(rule_set$if_you_see, str_detect, string = text) %>% 
           apply(1, function(x) paste(rule_set$write[x], collapse = ", ")))
```

Comment: This worked! I will wait for any stringr solution and then accept the final answer.

Comment: @Geet Well, I have eddited my answer including the use of a stringr function in the text matching.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 'tidy' solution:

Use `setNames` to form terminological pairs:

```
replacements <- setNames(rule_set$write, rule_set$if_you_see)
```

Use `replacements` in a pipe:

```
library(tidyverse)

to_be_classified %>%
  mutate(
    # replace values in `if_you_see` with values in `write`:
    class = str_replace_all(text, replacements),
    # extract and list occurrences of "car" and "human":
    class = lapply(str_extract_all(class, "car|human"), toString)) %>%
  # unnest listed items:
  unnest(where(is.list))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  text                                      class     
  <chr>                                     <chr>     
1 I have a honda civic. It pretty good.     car       
2 The toyota camery is also good. I like it car       
3 That boy has a honda CRV.                 human, car
4 You see that girl in blue dress?          human
```

Comment: Interesting @chris-ruehlemann to scale this solution up, we can generalize the manual pattern of "car|human" to paste0(rule_set$write, collapse = "|").

Comment: Yes, absolutely!

Comment: leveraged your solution to get to this using map_chr to_be_classified %>% 
  mutate(class = str_replace_all(string = text, pattern = replacements),
         class = map_chr(.x = str_extract_all(string = class, 
                                              pattern = paste0(rule_set$write %>% unique(), collapse = "|")), 
                         .f = toString)) %>%
  unnest(class)